# tokeninput in rails not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, jquery-tokeninput

I'm trying to run the tokeninput plugin on a field.

First of all the tutorial is mainly around adding id's from another associated model. I do not want to do that but just use a field from my own model (table) called `tags`.

currently when i type it it actions a /notes/tags.json ajax call but nothing is being returned, am i doing it right?

Controller:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @notes = Note.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    @tag = Note.where('tag LIKE ?', "%#{params[:q]}%")
  end
```

Model:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :tag

  def self.search(search)
    if search
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%")
    else
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: also i think you want this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Comment: my routes are just normal 'resources :notes' am i meant to something different? also should token input work with how i'm using it? anyways i'm not even getting a json return.

Comment: /notes/tags.json doesnt map to a route. . . is there a sample project you can post on github? there's more than one thing you'll need to do

Comment: if you attempt to go to /notes/tags.json in your browser you should get a routing error

Comment: can you add your tokeninput javascript code?

Comment: here's my repo https://github.com/glennmartinez/QaBase

Comment: and that's the 'playaround' branch

Comment: your asset pipeline needs fixing .. I've forked it and I will submit a pull request with the autocomplete field shortly.

Comment: Oh great, so your saying its fine to use the token-input with a field from the same model? The tutorial showed it stored id's so i'm thinking will it store id's from its own model?

Comment: just an update i can do get a query working but having problems saving it.

Comment: ah .. you may need to make a getter and setter on the field you wish to save them to .. have you followed the railscast? http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok: this is a rough but working example using jquery autocomplete

https://github.com/glennmartinez/QaBase/pull/1

The steps are as follows:

- make a route that responds to a json request (I hijacked the index action)
- Either declare the path or the data itself in the `data-autocomplete-source` attribute on the text field  eg: `<%= f.text_area :my_token_field, 'data-autocomplete-source' => features_path`
- create the javascript which attaches to the field referencing the ID (check the html source for this)
- submit the form and inspect the post-request-hash in the logger and run any `before_save` transformations you need to make the fields work.

Using TOKENINPUT and following http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields  AND looking at the example on the plugins page it expects your data to be in this format

```
[
  {"id":"856","name":"House"},
  {"id":"1035","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
  ...
]
```

You can create that same hash by referencing something different in the ID .. for example

```
Notes.all.map { |n| {:id => n.tag, :name => n.name } }.to_json
```

which will generate something like:

```
[
  {"id":"tagname","name":"House"},
  {"id":"othertagname","name":"Desperate Housewives"},
  ...
]
```

You can then tell the response fields to search the table by the tag name.

Of course you will need to create some kind of uniqueness on these in order to manage only returning 1 record.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, i've merged your pull request and the autocomplete stuff is not there, only whitespace deletion which i didn't really need.

Comment: please use github issues to further debug this